# I have 2 pieces of xquery codes where 1 gives the right result but 2 doesnt. Why?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I am supposed to display the country names where more than half the population speaks German.

## 1 The code below gives the correct result

Code

```
doc("countries.xml")//country/language[contains(.,"German") and data(@percentage)>50]/../data(@name)
```

## 2 This code below doesn't give the correct answer.

Code

```
let $d:=doc("countries.xml")

for $p in $d/countries/country[language="German"] where data($p/language/@percentage)>50

return data($p/@name)
```

Problem: I am not able to understand why the first one works and second doesn't. If someone would be able to explain the flaw in my logic I would appreciate it.
Thank You

Here is a part of the xml data:

```
<country name="Belgium" population="10170241" area="30510">
<language percentage="32">French</language>
<language percentage="1">German</language>
<language percentage="56">Dutch</language>
</country>
```

Comment: To comply with the [mcve] definition, please ensure that the part of the data you provide is complete enough someone can run your query against it without changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constraints are different in these two queries. In the first query, you are applying both constraints to the same `language`:

```
language[contains(.,"German") and data(@percentage)>50]
```

In the second query, `$p` is `/country[language="German"]`, and then it is also constrained to `data($p/language/@percentage)>50`. But the `language` in these two constraints are not guaranteed to be the same, only within the same country, so the query matches if any `language/@percentage > 50` and any `language="German"` within the same country.

You want to apply both constraints to the same language:

```
for $p in $doc/countries/country
where $p/language[@percentage >50 and contains(.,"German")]
return $p/@name
```

Comment: Note also that `language[contains(."German")]` will match "Germanic", whereas `language[. = "German"]` won't. However (although we haven't been given definitive information) the reason for the discrepancy is probably that `country[language='German']` matches any country where at least one of the language children is "German".

Comment: Thank you so much. It totally makes sense now. appreciate it.